# Is it possible to alter PGSync to work with other sorts of search engines that aren't ElasticSearch?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, pgsync

Looking to sync my postgres database with a vector search engine (weaviate) but it's new so there are no tools to do that. I was thinking about work arounds and came across PGSync which basically does this but with ElasticSearch. Would it be possible to alter PGSync in some way to get it to work with weaviate or any other search engine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PGSync only works with Elasticsearch at the moment. With a bit of effort, you could possibly get it to work with another data sink.

[PGSync](https://pgsync.com/) is now fully compatible with [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/)